# Are there still use-cases for ECL?

Tags: digital-logic

I learned about ECL (Emitter Coupled Logic), but I never found devices or use-cases. Is ECL a historic topic or are there still use-cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digi-Key still has thousands of active part numbers. Most Popular are the analog input comparators with extreme speed and symmetrical slew and delay on outputs and also [prescaler counters](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC10EL33-D.PDF) in the 4~5GHz range.

Complementary ECL has its speed and no spikes for egress ( both conducted and radiated) The low noise emission from complementary ouput signals that are perfectly matched cancel each other out and consumes constant supply current, unlike CMOS.

The 100 Series contains temperature compensation.

Comment: So, these devices are for very high frequences applications? Could you name a typical application?

Comment: 4.2GHz RF Synth PLL